# React Native: how to render an "underscript"?

Tags: react-native

I needed to create a simple project that has one extra-challenging requirement:

I need to implement an "**underscript**" (if such a word exists) on certain texts.

The original texts look like this below and I need to put the same style in the mobile app:

```
the quick brown fox jumps over    // <-- normal text
    +   - -   +  -  =             // <-- "underscripts", directly under specific letters
```

I only needed to "underscript" three characters so far: +, -, =

One solution I found was changing the style to do [a superscript or subscript](https://aboutreact.com/react-native-show-superscript-and-subscript/). This is a good approach but this would have problems when aligning it to the exact letters. There is no pattern as to where the plus and minuses are gonna be positioned. The positions are gonna be hard-coded (or set in a config file) based on the original text I'm trying to code.

Is there some simpler and programmatic way to do so?

Comment: 'The positions are gonna be hard-coded (or set in a config file)' how are you maintaining this ? array with indexes ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan If I'm gonna render the underscripts separately from the Text component, then yeah I'm gonna put them in array with indexes. Loop through each and put them at positions.

But if its possible to render both the text and the underscript, then I may not need to put it in a config file.

Comment: Better to create a custom component and style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Guruparan Giritharan, I just made a custom component and style for the meantime.

I just embedded the + and - inside the given string. The underscript is just a transparent version of the original string. If its not a + and -, make it transparent. If it is, then print it visibly.

```
function TextUnderScript({ inputString }) {
  const underScripts = []
  var inputLength = inputString.length
  for (var i = 0; i < inputLength; i++) {
    if(inputString.charAt(i) === '+') {
      underScripts.push(  <Text style={styles.readFont}>+</Text>  )
      i++
    } else if(inputString.charAt(i) === '-') {
      underScripts.push(  <Text style={styles.readFont}>-</Text>  )
      i++
    } else if(inputString.charAt(i) === '=') {
      underScripts.push(  <Text style={styles.readFont}>=</Text>  )
      i++
    } else {
      underScripts.push(  <Text style={styles.readFontTransparent}>{inputString.charAt(i)}</Text> )
    }
  }
...
}
```

[source snack](https://snack.expo.io/@machneils250/f34787)

(might as well mark this as an answer then xD)